# Docker ~ Pasting into an interactive PowerShell Terminal

Tags: powershell, docker

I have the following problem:

On a Windows Machine, I am using the PowerShell CLI to run a Container that runs microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express. I can open an interactive PowerShell session in that container using the command "docker exec -it my_container powershell", but in that interactive terminal, I can't paste any text from outside.

Say, I want to paste the following line:

```
echo (Get-ItemProperty -Path ‘Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment’ -Name PATH).path
```

Using [Ctrl]+[V] only returns the following (as opposed to the non-interactive docker PowerShell session PowerShell CLI, where this pastes the text without any problems):

```
^V
```

I have also tried right-clicking on the console background, or right-clicking on the console window title and then selecting [Edit] > [Paste]. However, this only delivers the following corrupted and truncated result:

```
echo (Get-ItemProperty -Path ?^?^?Registry::HKEY_LOC
```

I have already tried adding the following lines to my Dockerfile, as outlined on [this page](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29646):

```
WORKDIR "Program Files"
RUN rd /S /Q WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine
WORKDIR /
```

However, that only caused the following error when trying to build the image:

```
Step 11/12 : RUN rd /S /Q WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine
 ---> Running in 95497bbaf4cf
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'/Q'.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... e = 'SilentlyContinue'; rd /S /Q WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParentContai
   nsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

So, my question here is: Is it possible to paste into an interactive PowerShell session running in a container accessed over PowerShell? Or is this some kind of "inception"-Problem where the layering of different systems makes proper pasting impossible?